# How to access my data.json file in firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have the following project structure in my firebase project?

`public/
---css/
---index.html
---js/index.js
---img/
data/data.json`

In the index.js i am declaring the below variable, which is then passed to the jquery.JSON methods but my site is not able to get the data.

```
let url = ./../data/data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.  Firebase Hosting only deploys content within the "public" folder by default.  It doesn't deploy any files outside of that, so you won't be able to access them in the JavaScript code running in the browser.  You will have to move or copy that JSON file somewhere into public if you want to be able to make a request for it.

Comment: I moved the data folder into public and it started working